# Are similar questions archived when you delete them?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I was wondering whether the questions you delete are archived after deletion. I am still getting used to stack overflow and meta stack overflow, so would any of you be able to explain exactly what happens to these 'deleted' questions? Would I be able to ask same deleted question after few days or will it still pick it up saying that this was a deleted question?

Comment: Any reason you want to reask a deleted question.  Nothing is deleted unless it is of poor quality or is off topic (unless you delete it yourself)

Comment: My bad. My question is specifically pointing to the questions you've deleted yourself.

Comment: But why did you delete it if you want to reask?

Comment: It's not what I've done. I am asking about the process of the deleted question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing (or almost nothing) is truly deleted. Deleted questions (and answers) remain in the database and are visible to 10k+ users.

Additionally; asking questions then deleting them then re-asking them is risking an automatic question ban (which is caused by too many deleted,  downvoted and closed questions). All in all deleting and re-asking is not a good idea. Edit existing questions to make them better, don't delete and repost

Comment: How about deleted answers? For example you have answered your own question and deleted it. (Just done an experiment by leaving it for 20 minutes or so and deleted it). I can see my 'Deleted' answer, which now has grayish background, but from their point of view, would it be visible?

Comment: @user3315821 deleted answers are also visible to 10k+ users (users with more than 10,000 rep) and the user who posted them. Similarly to questions having a few deleted answers is fine, having loads may lead to an automatic answer ban.